# How do I change 'your text here' in vector files from Adobe Stock?

Tags: vector, text, stock-images

[image]I licensed a sheet of Vector from Adobe Stock that says "Your Text Here" in all of them but I don't know how to enter my own text.  Can you help?

Comment: What kind of file is it? What apps / programs do you have available?

Comment: Hi thanks, It's an Adobe Illustrator File. I have the latest Adobe Illustrator and Photoshop on a MAC.

Comment: I am using images from Adobe stock.                                                                          Here is a link to where I get them licensed.         https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/134566/i-licensed-a-sheet-of-vector-from-adobe-stock-that-says-your-text-here-in-all?noredirect=1#134566

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in Illustrator? Have you tried any tools? what happened? Please do some tests and [edit] your question to give us more details. Check [ask] to learn more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stock art almost always comes with the text converted to outlines. You can edit it as a regular vector shape by manipulating anchor points, but it is no longer editable as live text. Instead, you have to completely replace it with new text elements of your own. It might seem counter-intuitive for a company to offer text-based stock art with no live text, but these are usually intended more as a way to provide inspiration and save time by creating a framework for a specific style of graphic that you then finish with your own text elements.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that many stock art providers forbid including live text in stock art as it introduces legal issues with third party licenses that they don't want to manage or be responsible for.